# Why was "Oliver!" (1968) rated G?

Tags: content-rating, oliver

I'm surprised that *Oliver!* (1968) was rated G. It doesn't look like a G rated movie. It contains some strong violence and quite a bit of Drinking. It looks more like a PG film. So why was it rated G? What was the MPAA's justification when they rated this Movie G? This movie would never be rated G by today's standards.

Comment: For what it's worth, [Basil The Great Mouse Detective (1986)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091149/) featured drinking and the concept of having had one's drinks "drugged" and yet it only got a U. Or do you think "Oliver!"'s case is significant because of the era (the 60s)?

Comment: @Pharap and also a bit about brothels, albeit it probably went over most young viewer's heads.  It quite upset my mother when my younger sister would sing “Baby, I just want to be good to you” in the middle of a department store, but I didn't understand at the time.

Comment: @can-ned_food Good point, I'd almost forgotten that part. I'm kind of unsurprised though, I'm fairly certain there's more films and tv shows aimed at children/families with 'subtle' sexual references or implied sex than there are without.

Answer (score 49):

There was no "PG" in 1968, in either the US or UK.

US had G [General] or M [Mature] & no-one in their right mind would edit a family musical to get an M rating, so presumably they were well within the guidelines for the time.

In the UK in 1968 the options were U [Universal] or A [Adult] & as it was a British film, these would have been the specific guidelines it was probably made to.

A didn't even stand for 'advisory' until 1970, so the distinctions were far more broad. PG was introduced in 1972, US & 1982 UK.

Refs -
Wikipedia - [Motion Picture Association of America film rating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_Picture_Association_of_America_film_rating_system) &
British Board of Film Classification -  [History of the age ratings symbols](http://www.bbfc.co.uk/education-resources/student-guide/bbfc-history/history-age-ratings-symbols)

Comment: I think there's the general idea that families are intelligent and won't simply take a rating at face value and send their children off.  For crying out loud we have coffee cups with warning labels because people are now stupid.

Comment: In the US, they have warnings on car mirrors because of similar idiocy. [Jurassic Park ref, amongst others]

Comment: There was also the option of an X certificate in 1968 in the UK, not that you would make a family musical for that rating. Anyone who grew up watching Hammer Horrors remembers that certificate though.

Comment: @Nelson They probably have the labels for the 1% who would sue, so they can say "we warned you" to them.

Comment: Slightly off-topic but when I was a sophomore in high school, and too young to go see "R" movies, I wanted to go see the movie MASH. For whatever reason, my mother said "OK", grabbed me and one of my friends (I don't have a clue if his parents knew what was up) and took us to see it. She sat in the back, away from us, and I thought, "Wow! Now I get to see some *real* stuff!". Uhhh...no. One quick flash of one woman hitting the floor, lots of blood, and lots of swearing. I heard more cussing every day in high school. She asked, "Did you boys enjoy the film?" "Uh...yeah. Thanks, Mom..." :-)

Comment: @Nelson to be fair, we have warning labels on coffee because a certain large arrogant corporation served coffee literally a handful of degrees shy of boiling and despite numerous complaints and reports of injuries. It's common sense to expect coffee to be hot, but its *also* common sense not to expect it to be boiling.

Comment: @JaredSmith I don't agree at all. At home I pour the water for my tea/coffee out of a kettle that has just been boiled. Common sense tells me to expect that it will be "a handful of degrees shy of boiling".

Comment: @JBentley you can do whatever you want at home (although a thermometer reading might surprise you). Starbucks serves it between 145~155F (as do most shops unless you request extra hot). *Well* shy of boiling. McDonalds was serving it at 190F. Despite your glib comment I doubt you'd be willing to pour it straight from the kettle into your mouth.

Comment: @JaredSmith We're talking about common sense, not what a thermometer tells us, or the temperatures in specific shops that most people wouldn't know without looking up first. You're entirely correct, I would not be willing to pour it straight from the kettle into my mouth. Common sense tells me I will get a similar effect if I pour it from the kettle into the cup and *then* straight into my mouth. My comment was not intended to be glib at all - I genuinely expect my tea bought in a shop (and I assume this applies to coffee too) to burn me if I drink it as soon as it is served.

Comment: @JaredSmith Also consider that to correctly brew a cup of coffee or tea (green teas excepted), it *should* be at just under 100c. Again, talking purely common sense, I would expect a proper tea or coffee shop to know this, and my baseline assumption would be to expect that sort of temperature (absent the knowledge that they are doing something different). To legitimately achieve temperatures in the range you're talking without lowering the quality the drink needs to cool after brewing, but shops don't generally keep you waiting around for this to happen before handing it to you.

Comment: The actual details of what happened with the coffee is irrelevant.  The fact that we now need to print it on the cups simply means common sense is no longer expected.  People are blaming bad behavior on everything but themselves.  The rating, as anyone with common sense should know, is somewhat subjective and should be confirmed at a person, per-film basis.  This modern breakdown of PG-13, PG-16, whatever crap just means a lot of parents are now dumber than ever.

Comment: @Nelson what Jared Smith was pointing out was that there's more to the McDonald's coffee story than what you make it out to be.  I too used to use it to point out erosion of personal responsibility.  I've since changed my opinion after reading the facts of the case.

Comment: @JBentley That McDonald's had repeatedly received violations for _maintaining_ their coffee at near boiling temperatures.  And while common sense tells you that coffee is hot, I highly doubt most people would expect to be so hot it will result in being hospitalized for 8 days, skin grafts, and being disabled for 2 years if they spill it on themselves. Also the plaintiff in that case originally asked for only $20K, enough to cover her medical expenses and a few thousand to compensate her daughter for the time she took off work to care for her.  McDonalds offered $800.00 and refused to negotiate

Comment: @Nelson: Companies do not label hot beverage containers as hot because they believe their customers are becoming stupider. They do so because they believe that doing so will discourage their customers from suing them when they negligently and repeatedly engage in activities that could harm their customers. Putting a warning on a cup costs nothing; training your staff to not harm customers, that runs to money.

Comment: Hey, can we move this conversation to chat.  Its gone a long way from being directly relevant to Oliver!

Comment: iandotkelly, agreed, but would you allow me to post a link?  @Nelson, here's the information about the case: [Liebeck v. McDonald's Restaurants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liebeck_v._McDonald%27s_Restaurants).  Please read it so you don't spread misinformation.

Answer (score 15):

Because there was no PG when *Oliver!* was released. As per the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_Picture_Association_of_America_film_rating_system#From_M_to_GP_to_PG):

> The ratings used from 1968 to 1970 were: †1 †2
>
> Rated G: Suggested for General Audiences
>
> Rated M: Suggested for Mature Audiences – parental discretion advised
>
> Rated R: Restricted – persons under 16 not admitted, unless accompanied by parent or adult guardian.
>
> Rated X: Persons Under 16 Not Admitted

While the film might be on the stronger side of a G, it probably wasn't harsh enough to warrant an M rating.

†1: Kennedy, Matthew (2014). **Roadshow!: The Fall of Film Musicals in the 1960s.** OUP USA. p. 183. ISBN 9780199925674.
†2: Life Magazine. May 30, 1969. p. 55.